# Can I represent the beam deflection curve with the stanli package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing, engineering, stanli

With the `stanli` [package](https://ctan.org/pkg/stanli) one can easy and fast draw beam schemes. But I missing a possibility to draw a deflection curve of the beam. Maybe I overlooked something in the manual. Anyway, I solved it with the classic `draw` method of `TikZ`. See my code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{stanli}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    %the points
    \point{begin}{0}{0};
    \point{middle}{2.5}{0};
    \point{end}{5}{0};
    %the beam
    \beam{2}{begin}{end};
    %the support
    \support{3}{begin}[-90];
    %the load
    \load{1}{middle}[90];
    \load{1}{end}[90];
    %the inscription of the load
    \notation{1}{middle}{$F_1$};
    \notation{1}{end}{$F_2$};
    %the deflection curves
    \draw
      [-, ultra thick] (begin) .. controls (2.5, -.25) .. (5, -1)
      [-, ultra thick] (begin) .. controls (2.5, -1)   .. (5, -2.5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a possibility to do the lines 22 to 24 with `stanli`? If not, how can I implement this lines (if even) more elegant. Maybe automate, e. g. with `\foreach`, well with two deflection curves it isn't necessary, with more already. In short: How can I optimize this lines?

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the `stanli` package. So this is a suggestion to draw those lines in a way to make them look reasonable.

Here I'm using polar coordinates to make the lines end along a circle, and the radius is shortened more and more for each line to account for the bend.

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{stanli}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    %the points
    \point{begin}{0}{0};
    \point{middle}{2.5}{0};
    \point{end}{5}{0};
    %the beam
    \beam{2}{begin}{end};
    %the support
    \support{3}{begin}[-90];
    %the load
    \load{1}{middle}[90];
    \load{1}{end}[90];
    %the inscription of the load
    \notation{1}{middle}{$F_1$};
    \notation{1}{end}{$F_2$};
    %the deflection curves
% without correction
%    \foreach [evaluate={\in=180-\b*2}] \b in {5,10,...,30}
%      \draw[red,-, ultra thick] (begin) to[out=0,in=\in] (-\b:5);
% quater circle with full radius
%    \draw[red] (begin) -- (end) arc (0:-90:5) -- cycle;
% polar coordinates with some correction of the radius to account for bend
    \foreach [evaluate={\in=180-\b*2}] \b in {5,10,...,30}{
      \draw[-, ultra thick] (begin) to[out=0,in=\in] (-\b:5-\b*0.01);
% quater circles with sortened radius
%      \draw[red] (begin) -- (5-\b*0.01,0) arc (0:-90:5-\b*0.01) -- cycle;
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Mike for your answer! That is enough for my purpose. I couldn't found nothing about the command `\in` in the `TikZ & PGF` manual. Couldt you please explain it?

Comment: @Su-47 the `\in` is a macro name i chose, it is defined by `evaluate` for each round of the `\foreach` loop. See pgf manual for 3.0.1.a, page 904.