# How can one accent with TikZ the space between curved lines?

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing, engineering

This question continues my [another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394815/can-i-represent-the-beam-deflection-curve-with-the-stanli-package). I solved this task (lines 31 to 42) with braces from the `decorations.pathreplacing` library of `TikZ`. My code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{stanli}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    %the points
    \point{begin}{0}{0};
    \point{middle}{2.5}{0};
    \point{end}{5}{0};
    %the beam
    \beam{2}{begin}{end};
    %the support
    \support{3}{begin}[-90];
    %the load
    \load{1}{middle}[90];
    \load{1}{end}[90];
    %the inscription of the load
    \notation{1}{middle}{$F_1$};
    \notation{1}{end}{$F_2$};
    %the deflection curves
    \foreach
      [evaluate = {\in = 180 - \angle * 2}] \angle in {20, 40}
    \draw
      [-, ultra thick] (begin) to [out = 0, in = \in] (-\angle : 5);
    %circular sector as helplines
    \draw
      [blue, dotted] (begin) -- (middle) arc (0 : -90 : 2.5) -- cycle
                     (begin) -- (end)    arc (0 : -90 : 5)   -- cycle;
    %the inscription of the deflection
    \draw
      [decorate, red, decoration = brace] (2.5, -.03)   -- (2.48, -.34)
      node[right, midway] {\scriptsize$w_{11}$};
    \draw
      [decorate, red, decoration = brace] (2.475, -.39) -- (2.38, -.75)
      node[right, midway] {\scriptsize$w_{12}$};
    \draw
      [decorate, red, decoration = brace] (5, -.03)     -- (4.71, -1.69)
      node[right, midway] {\scriptsize$w_{21}$};
    \draw
      [decorate, red, decoration = brace] (4.68, -1.73) -- (3.85, -3.21)
      node[right, midway] {\scriptsize$w_{22}$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I think it is a very bad solution, because I repeat always almost the same code pieces and the point definitions (where the brace begins and ends) made by try and error. At the end the labels of the braces should be rotated in the direction in which the brace shows. In short: How can one solve this task in a bit automate and optimal manner. Any optimizations and also completely different solutions are welcome!

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You have already the coordinates `middle` and `end`, which can be used for a couple of the coordinates. You can add e.g. `coordinate (ang\angle)` at the end of the path that draws the deflection lines to add named coordinates there. To get the last coordinates you can use the `intersections` library. Finally, to rotate the nodes you can make use of the `let` syntax from the `calc` library. Here I wrapped that in a macro.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{stanli}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,intersections}
\newcommand\inscription[4][]{%
  \draw
   let
   \p1=(#2),\p2=(#3),\n1={atan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)+90}
   in
   [inscription,#1] (#2) -- (#3) node[rotate=\n1] {#4};
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
      inscription/.style={
        decoration = {brace,raise=0.5pt}, % raise moves the brace in the direction it's pointing
        decorate,
        red,
        shorten >=0.8pt, % half the linewidth of ultra thick
        shorten <=0.8pt,
        every node/.style={midway,right,font=\scriptsize}
      },
      arcs/.style={blue,dotted}    
  ]

    %the points
    \point{begin}{0}{0};
    \point{middle}{2.5}{0};
    \point{end}{5}{0};
    %the beam
    \beam{2}{begin}{end};
    %the support
    \support{3}{begin}[-90];
    %the load
    \load{1}{middle}[90];
    \load{1}{end}[90];
    %the inscription of the load
    \notation{1}{middle}{$F_1$};
    \notation{1}{end}{$F_2$};
    %the deflection curves
    \foreach
      [evaluate = {\in = 180 - \angle * 2}] \angle in {20, 40}
    \draw
      [-, ultra thick,name path=defl\angle] (begin) to [out = 0, in = \in] (-\angle : 5) coordinate (ang\angle);
    %circular sector as helplines
    \draw  [arcs,name path=arc1] (begin) -- (middle) arc (0 : -90 : 2.5) -- cycle;
    \draw  [arcs]                (begin) -- (end)    arc (0 : -90 : 5)   -- cycle;
    % find intersections between inner sector and deflections
    \path [
           name intersections={of=defl20 and arc1,by={,D1}}, % first intersection is at "begin", so leave first name empty
           name intersections={of=defl40 and arc1,by={,D2}}];
    %the inscription of the deflection
    \inscription{middle}{D1}{$w_{11}$}
    \inscription{D1}{D2}{$w_{12}$}
    \inscription{end}{ang20}{$w_{21}$}
    \inscription{ang20}{ang40}{$w_{22}$}

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @Torbjørn T.! Thank you for your answer! It's a bit tricky for me. My questions so far:
**1.** What do the empty `[]` in the line `\newcommand\inscription[4][]{`?
**2.** I don't understand this calculation `\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1`?
**3.** Why do the name of the macro in the definition of the macro (I mean this `[inscription,#1]`)?

Comment: @Su-47 1. Brackets like that indicate that the first argument to the macro (`#1`) is optional, and the contents of the brackets is the default value of the argument. 2. You've just listed the argument to the `atan2` function there. When defining `\p1=(a)`, `\x1` holds the x-coord of `a`, and `\y1` the y-coord. 3. It doesn't refer to the macro, it's the name of the style I define later.

Comment: Hello @Torbjørn T., thank you for your answers! I have unclear expressed the second question. Sorry. I understood that `\p(#number)` are points and `\y#number`,`\x#number` whose coordinates. I meant the calculation `\y2-\y1` and `\x2-\x1`. What makes you think that? What is achieved thereby? To **1.** The optional argument, how I understand, is `#1` in `[inscription,#1]`. But where in the code do you use it? Sorry for my incorrect english and so much questions. I only wish to understand it in detail, only then I can learn something about it.

Comment: @Su-47 The optional argument isn't actually used anywhere, I added it just in case it might be useful to control the style of the brace and label, e.g. you could do `\inscription[blue]{middle}{D1}{$w_{11}$}` to change colour. As for the calculation:  Draw a line from the first point to the second, and consider that as the hypotenuse of a right triangle, the legs being horizontal and vertical.  Obviously `\y1-\y2` is the length of the vertical leg, while `\x2-\x1` is the length of the horizontal leg. `atan2(\y1-\y2, \x2-\x1)` calculates the angle.

Comment: Hello @Torbjørn T., thank you for your answers! One thing: In your comment above, you write `\y1-\y2`. Should it be `\y2-\y1` instead? Otherwise the angle of the labels (of the braces) is bigger than 90°. New question: `shorten >=0.8pt` and `shorten <=0.8pt`. I understand what it does. In the `TikZ` manual it used everywhere, but no description about it is available there. And why I must to add a whitespace before `>` or `<` (`shorten >=0.8pt` and `shorten <=0.8pt`). Without the white space it doesn't work.

Comment: @Su-47 Sorry, `\y1-\y2` was obviously a typo. Why do expect it work without the space? The keys are called `shorten >` and `shorten <`, with the space. Just like you have to write `line width` or `text width`, and not `linewidth` or `textwidth`, that's how they are defined. Odd that it's not described in the manual though, I thought it was, but looks like only the lower-level `\pgfsetshortenstart` and `\pgfsetshortenend` are described (section 99.3).

Comment: Hello @Torbjørn T., thank you for your answers! Sorry for the long delay. Now is all clear!